# IE 11.1324 text in a disabled fieldset can be removed. ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, bootstrap-4, devexpress, internet-explorer-11

I have a fieldset which can dynamically be set to Disabled based on the user role. This works fine in Chrome and Opera. However, in IE 11.1324 I have the issue that text can't be added, but it can be removed. The data cannot be saved however, but it's still confusing for the user. Is there a known way to fix this?

```
Code used to disable the field:
if (currentUser.Role == "Employee")
            {
                fieldset.Disabled = true;
            }
```